# Importing .csv with scientific notation into R to preserve scientific notation?

Tags: r

I have a CSV dataframe that looks like this:

```
SNPID,chr,position,coded_all,noncoded_all,beta,SE,pval
rs10,7,92221824,a,c,0.0176,0.0182,0.3333
rs1000000,12,125456933,a,g,0.0195,0.0076,0.009999
rs10000010,4,21227772,t,c,0.0077,0.0062,0.215
rs10000012,4,1347325,c,g,0.0098,0.0093,0.2901
```

The values in the `pval` column range from 0-1, and many are in scientific notation. When I imported this into R using `readr` with `pval` as `numeric`, the values in the `pval` that were in scientific did not appeared only as numbers. For example `9.996e-003` appears only as `9.996`.

To get around this, I have imported the dataframe with `p-val` as character and I coerced it to numeric using `as.numeric`. This still caused the same problem. Is there any other way around this?

Comment: I am not able to replicate your problem. For example, `dat <- read.table(text="rs10000012,4,1347325,c,g,0.0098,0.0093,2.901e-003", sep=",")` works fine for the final variable.

Comment: I could not replicate with `readr` either: `read_csv("SNPID,chr,position,coded_all,noncoded_all,beta,SE,pval\nrs10000012,4,1347325,c,g,0.0098,0.0093,2.901e-003")`. Please provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: The file is huge... so I read it in initially with: crp_num <- read_csv("~/Sync/PRSice_v1-2.25/2017-2-14 15.42.3-CRP.METAL.19.06.2009.AllSNPs.csv", 
    col_types = cols(ClosestRefGene = col_skip(), 
        Direction = col_skip(), SE = col_number(), 
        beta = col_number(), pval = col_number()))

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- data.frame(pval = c("1e6", "9.996e-003"))

df$pval2 <- sapply(strsplit(as.character(df$pval), 'e'), 
               function(x) as.numeric(x[1]) * 10^as.numeric(x[2]) )
```